# MYSQL - Trigger On Insert - copy to

Tags: mysql, triggers

We have a table which has IT incident tickets called ticket_data.  I want when new tickets are inserted into if the criteria of if certain criteria is met (ticket logged today, logged by teams like 'MCO-TechServ%' and logged_via = 'Phone' then copy the row to the table ticket_data_sd_today

Im doing this as there are many reports which are reported on today's service desk tickets and I thought it would be easier to create a table with the day's tickets  which gets purged daily.

I have tried to create a trigger to copy the row after insert but it's not working.  Can anyone help?  Thank you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sdinfo`.`todays_tickets`AFTER INSERT ON `ticket_data`
FOR EACH ROW
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
IF (date(new.`logged_date_time`) = curdate() 
and new.`logged_by_team` like 'MCO-TechServ%'
and new.`logged_via` = 'Phone') then

INSERT INTO ticketicket_data_sd_today 
(`Ticket_Number,Logged_Date_Time,Call_Type,Call_Detail)
values (new.Ticket_Number,new.Logged_Date_Time,new.Call_Type,new.Call_Detail);
 end if;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: move the `DELIMITER $$` *before* the `CREATE TRIGGER`.  (That's a separate statement. It's not part of the create trigger statement.)

Comment: You also have some stray backticks in the `INSERT` statement.  Could you post the exact error message you are getting?